# Assistance Needed: Trouble Running Bare-Metal Code on second core in Cyclone V SoC

Tags: arm, intel, bare-metal, intel-fpga, soc

I  am working on intel cyclone 5 hps I have two cores in a processor Core 0 core 1, I want two code to run on two different cores core 0 and core 1 in bare metal.

When I run in jtag mode it works, for jtag i first debug using core 0 where i take core 1 out of reset it, than debug core 1 usign jtag it work

BUT, When i want to run both core usign qspi it only run core 0 not core 1

Here is the step i followed

Firsly, loading preloader quartus_hps -c 1 -o P preloader-mkpimage.bin

I make an image from bin file of core 0 and place it to qspi

mkimage -A arm -O u-boot -T standalone -C none -a 0x00060000 -e 0 -n "baremetal image" -d core0.bin core0.img

quartus_hps -c 1 -o P -a 0x00060000 core0.img

I make an image from bin file of core 1 and place it to qspi mkimage -A arm -O u-boot -T standalone -C none -a 0x00100000 -e 0 -n "baremetal image" -d core1.bin core1.img quartus_hps -c 1 -o P -a 0x00100000 core1.bin

When i restart board only that code work which is in core 0, core 1 code not executing

I am setting cpu1startaddress 100000 apart from that in the code of core 0 also i am using alt_qspi function to to place bin file data in ddr,

I want to run in smp mode so I also set required aux_control_register smp and fw bit as stated in tech ref manual

alt_qspi_read((uint32_t *)BL_START/ddr3 address/, 0x100000/qspi address/, 0x40000);

In linker/scat file core 0 entry point is 0x60000 and

linker/scat file core 1 entry point is 0x100000

As suggested in the previous query

[Query](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/701112/assistance-needed-trouble-running-bare-metal-code-on-second-core-in-cyclone-v-s)

I combined both programs into a single image file so that the preloaded will load both into RAM

The **problem is whenever** second core come out of reset it goes to 0x0 address but I want it to be at 0x100000 I think I need to set vector table such that **whenever second core come out of reset it goes to 0x100000 address but I am unable to find where to do these configuration**